# Get Top Item in Scrolled Listbox VBA

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba

I have an Access Database that has a listbox on a form. This list can be scrolled through, but I need to know what the top item is once the list has been scrolled.

I am wanting to create a synchronised view similar to a Gantt view that will sit next to the list, (which I already have the code to do) but I could do with being able to find out what the top item is so I know which item needs to be at the top in the synchronised view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You probably mean the top row of the displayed rows. But the ID of this is not exposed in Access. The user must select a row and then your code can sync the chart to the ID of this.

Comment: start macro recording then scroll the listbox a few times. maybe something of use will get recorded

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list method followed by the index. For example to display in a MsgBox then you can use:

```
MsgBox ComboBox1.List(0)
```

Where 0 is the 1st item in the list
1 is the second etc, etc

Hope that helps

EDIT:

Here is the code that I tried as a test and it worked fine.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click
MsgBox ListBox1.List(0)
End Sub



Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem "a"
UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem "b"
UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem "c"
UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem "d"
UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem "e"
End Sub
```

This shows a Message Box with the Letter "a" inside, as that is the first item added to the ListBox (The code to populate is included to show it is added first). If you are wanting to show literally the first item in the ListBox, then this will work. If you are looking to show the top in the list at the time (Based on whether the user has scrolled) then let me know and I will try and work on for a solution to this

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that, I'm a little confused by that. I'm using a listbox that can be scrolled down by the user on the form. I won't know where they have scrolled to so I won't know the index to get the item data for. That's why I was wondering if there was something like listbox.topindex in vba

Comment: (0) will always reference the top item from the ComboBox. I thought that's what you wanted?

Comment: Should be the same in a listbox

Comment: Sorry, no I'm using a list and in VBA which restricts things a bit.

Comment: Please view the edit on the answer/ This is all in vba :)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. Yes I can get the topmost item in the listbox by referencing the zero index, but I need to get the top item shown when the listbox is scrolled. (Similar to listbox.topindex in VB.NET) The application I've got is displaying a set of tasks with dates against them in a listbox. Alongside this listbox is a webbrowser that is displaying a gantt view (created using html and css from the dates in the first listbox) So I could do with knowing what the top visible item is so I can recreate the gantt view as I can't synchronise the scrolling of the listbox and web browser.